# Remove certain elements in a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts as follows:

```
l1=[{"key1":"a1","key2":"a2"}, {"key1":"b1","key2":"b2"},
    {"key1":"c1","key2":"c2"}, {"key1":"a2","key2":"a1"},
    {"key1":"c2","key2":"c1"}, ....]
```

I want to remove the repeated elements in the dict.For example,if I have a1 and a2, once in the list of dicts,I don't want them again.So,in the above example,I don't want the dicts

```
{"key1":"a2","key2":"a1"},{"key1":"c2","key2":"c1"}
```

How do I delete them?
Basically I want to remove the dicts having same values irrespective of their order.
I have tried the following code:

```
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
  for key,val in l1[i].items():
      if l[i][key]==l[i+1][key]
         del l[i+1][key]
```

This doesn't work

Comment: l1 is a list - not a dict. You want to remove duplicate elements of a list when the elements are identically filled dicts?

Comment: isn't a1 and a2 diff in key1 and key2, how they r duplicate ?

Comment: Those are not duplicate - the one dict has `'key1'='a2'` the other `'key1'='a1'` and vice versa - [edit] with better/more examples and _reasoning_ please.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I want to remove the dicts based on values not based on keys,I want to remove the dicts having same values

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes they are different but that doesn't matter in my case because I want to remove the dicts with same values irrespective of whether they are assigned to same key or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict(list)` to collect under keys of `frozenset` of the values of your source list inner dict's and collect the actual dicts as values.

Iterate the `defaultdict(list)` and keep f.e. the 1st entry of each of its value lists:

```
l1=[{"key1":"a1","key2":"a2"},{"key1":"b1","key2":"b2"},
    {"key1":"c1","key2":"c2"},{"key1":"a2","key2":"a1"},
    {"key1":"c2","key2":"c1"}]

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)

# store dicts under the values of itself - use frozendict for key to 
# ignore order of values 
for inner in l1:
    d[frozenset(inner.values())].append(inner)

# construct new dict by f.e. keeping the first dict out of each list
l2 = [v[0] for _,v in d.items()] 

# pretty print them
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
pprint(l2)
```

Output:

```
# intermediate dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {frozenset({'a1', 'a2'}): [{'key1': 'a1', 'key2': 'a2'},
                                       {'key1': 'a2', 'key2': 'a1'}],
             frozenset({'b2', 'b1'}): [{'key1': 'b1', 'key2': 'b2'}],
             frozenset({'c1', 'c2'}): [{'key1': 'c1', 'key2': 'c2'},
                                       {'key1': 'c2', 'key2': 'c1'}]})
# resulting dict
[{'key1': 'a1', 'key2': 'a2'},
 {'key1': 'b1', 'key2': 'b2'},
 {'key1': 'c1', 'key2': 'c2'}]
```

See [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) abd [pretty printer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

---

In case you can not use defaultdict, you can use a normal one as well - it is just not as performant:

```
d = {}
for inner in l1:  
    d.setdefault(frozenset(inner.values()),[]).append(inner)
```

Comment: When I use defaultdict,the code starting from that line doesn't work anymore.It is  something wierd.Does it got something to do with version thing?

Comment: @sam version thing? What version do you use?  You can use a normal dict as well if you do: `d = {}; for inner in l1:  d.setdefault(frozenset(inner.values()),[]).append(inner)` - this is somewhat less performant though